# XML to XML with XSLT omitting specific elements based on value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to produce an xml file that is pretty much identical to the initial one, but I need my xsl sheet to transform it to only include those with a < type > of either 'apartment' or 'unit' and have a value of more than 1 in < numberofBedrooms > I'm completely lost, any help would be greatly appreciated!

my initial xml sheet is as following:

```
<rentalProperties> 
<property available="yes" contact="0423020892"> 
    <type>house</type> 
    <price>800</price> 
    <address> 
        <streetNo>116</streetNo> 
        <street>Warrigal Road</street> 
        <suburb>Camberwell</suburb> 
        <state>VIC</state> 
    <zipcode>3124</zipcode>
    </address> 
    <numberOfBedrooms>4</numberOfBedrooms> 
    <description>Ideal for the familly is this charming Californian Bungalow. Comprising a spacious living area, formal dining room plus a huge family/meals area, bright modern well appointed kitchen with dishwasher, gas cooktop and electric oven and heaps of bench space, Four double bedrooms, two in a wing of their own, are served by a stylishly renovated central bathroom and second sky-lit bathroom to the rear.</description>
</property>
</rentalproperties>
```

My xsl:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="RentalProperties">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="rentalProperties/property"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rentalProperties/property/type">
<xsl:element name="type" >
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rentalProperties/property/price">
<xsl:element name="price" >
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rentalProperties/property/address">
<xsl:element name="address" >
  <xsl:value-of select="streetNo"/><xsl:value-of select="street"/><xsl:value-of select="suburb"/><xsl:value-of select="state"/><xsl:value-of select="zipcode"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rentalProperties/property/numberOfBedrooms">
<xsl:element name="numberOfBedrooms" >
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rentalProperties/property/description">
<xsl:element name="description" >
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The output would be something like:

```
<RentalProperties>
<property>
<type>apartment</type>
<price>400</price>
<address>4/3,Acheron Avenue,Camberwell,VIC,3124, Australia</address>
<numberOfBedrooms>2</numberOfBedrooms>
<description>This two bedroom apartment is located in quiet tree lined street, just minutes from tram and easy walk to Camberwell Junction and train. Positioned on the 1st floor with sunny north facing lounge and balcony.
</description>
</property>
</RentalProperties>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an appropriate input. With both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is probably one of the simplest possible solutions (no explicit conditionals at all, all output is produced only by the identity template)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "property
   [not(contains('|unit|apartment|',
                 concat('|',type,'|')
                 )
        )
    or
     not(numberOfBedrooms > 1)
   ]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided one -- corrected and enlarged):

```
<rentalProperties>
<property available="yes" contact="0423020892">
    <type>house</type>
    <price>800</price>
    <address>
        <streetNo>116</streetNo>
        <street>Warrigal Road</street>
        <suburb>Camberwell</suburb>
        <state>VIC</state>
    <zipcode>3124</zipcode>
    </address>
    <numberOfBedrooms>4</numberOfBedrooms>
    <description>Ideal for the familly is this charming Californian Bungalow. Comprising a spacious living area, formal dining room plus a huge family/meals area, bright modern well appointed kitchen with dishwasher, gas cooktop and electric oven and heaps of bench space, Four double bedrooms, two in a wing of their own, are served by a stylishly renovated central bathroom and second sky-lit bathroom to the rear.</description>
</property>
<property available="yes" contact="0423020899">
    <type>apartment</type>
    <price>500</price>
    <address>
        <streetNo>116</streetNo>
        <street>Water St.</street>
        <suburb>Hornsby</suburb>
        <state>NSW</state>
    <zipcode>2012</zipcode>
    </address>
    <numberOfBedrooms>2</numberOfBedrooms>
    <description>Ideal for the familly is this charming Californian Bungalow. Comprising a spacious living area, formal dining room plus a huge family/meals area, bright modern well appointed kitchen with dishwasher, gas cooktop and electric oven and heaps of bench space, Four double bedrooms, two in a wing of their own, are served by a stylishly renovated central bathroom and second sky-lit bathroom to the rear.</description>
</property>
<property available="yes" contact="0423011111">
    <type>unit</type>
    <price>800</price>
    <address>
        <streetNo>7</streetNo>
        <street>Ryan St</street>
        <suburb>Isacs</suburb>
        <state>ACT</state>
    <zipcode>2603</zipcode>
    </address>
    <numberOfBedrooms>1</numberOfBedrooms>
    <description>Ideal for the familly is this charming Californian Bungalow. Comprising a spacious living area, formal dining room plus a huge family/meals area, bright modern well appointed kitchen with dishwasher, gas cooktop and electric oven and heaps of bench space, Four double bedrooms, two in a wing of their own, are served by a stylishly renovated central bathroom and second sky-lit bathroom to the rear.</description>
</property>
<property available="yes" contact="04231234567">
    <type>hotel</type>
    <price>1200</price>
    <address>
        <streetNo>4</streetNo>
        <street>Bench St.</street>
        <suburb>Deakin</suburb>
        <state>ACT</state>
    <zipcode>2600</zipcode>
    </address>
    <numberOfBedrooms>4</numberOfBedrooms>
    <description>Ideal for the familly is this charming Californian Bungalow. Comprising a spacious living area, formal dining room plus a huge family/meals area, bright modern well appointed kitchen with dishwasher, gas cooktop and electric oven and heaps of bench space, Four double bedrooms, two in a wing of their own, are served by a stylishly renovated central bathroom and second sky-lit bathroom to the rear.</description>
</property>
</rentalProperties>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (only one of the properties that meets all constraints is output):

```
<rentalProperties>
   <property available="yes" contact="0423020899">
      <type>apartment</type>
      <price>500</price>
      <address>
         <streetNo>116</streetNo>
         <street>Water St.</street>
         <suburb>Hornsby</suburb>
         <state>NSW</state>
         <zipcode>2012</zipcode>
      </address>
      <numberOfBedrooms>2</numberOfBedrooms>
      <description>Ideal for the familly is this charming Californian Bungalow. Comprising a spacious living area, formal dining room plus a huge family/meals area, bright modern well appointed kitchen with dishwasher, gas cooktop and electric oven and heaps of bench space, Four double bedrooms, two in a wing of their own, are served by a stylishly renovated central bathroom and second sky-lit bathroom to the rear.</description>
   </property>
</rentalProperties>
```

**Explanation**: Overriding the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** with an empty template matching any unwanted property.

Comment: Thankyou very very much, you're answer was spot on and amazingly helpful in making me understand what's happening. The dpawson link is a great reference too. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(./type/text()) = 'unit' or normalize-space(./type/text()) = 'apartment'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above xml copies everything to output but in the case of "property" element it only copies it if the type contains the text apartment or unit. I hope I gave you a hint..