# How do I use the information in one xml file to create another in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a really large xml file that has some information I am interested in, but I need to present it in another way. Let me illustrate:

SOURCE XML

```
<root attribute1="something" attribute2="somethingelse">
<items>
  <item id="dontcare" name="Need This Name 1" url="http://NeedThisUrl1.com">
    <availability>
      <instores/>
    </availability>
  </item>
  <item id="dontcare" name="Need This Name 2" url="http://NeedThisUrl2.com">
    <availability>
      <instores/>
    </availability>
  </item>
</items>
</root>
```

RESULT XML

```
<Items>
    <Item Attribute1="HardcodedValue1" Attribute2="HardcodedValue2">
      <Parameter Name="Id">Hardcoded Value</Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="Name">Need This Name 1</Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="Url">http://NeedThisUrl1.com</Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="Availability">Hardcoded Value</Parameter>
    </Item>
    <Item Attribute1="HardcodedValue1" Attribute2="HardcodedValue2">
      <Parameter Name="Id">Hardcoded Value</Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="Name">Need This Name 2</Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="Url">http://NeedThisUrl2.com</Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="Availability">Hardcoded Value</Parameter>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Best thing is to use Linq for XML.  There are numerous examples available.  You want to get all the Elements of xdoc.Elements("items") then convert the attributes to elements in the new document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try your hand at [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). Here's a few examples:

[Converting XML file to another XML file using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002772/converting-xml-file-to-another-xml-file-using-xslt)

[XML to XML with XSLT omitting specific elements based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863660/xml-to-xml-with-xslt-omitting-specific-elements-based-on-value?rq=1)

And this is an example on how to use C# to achieve that:

[How to apply an XSLT Stylesheet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up going with this. How did I *not* know about XSLT?! Thank you

Comment: @Freakishly There's always something we don't know, and that's the fun of it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use C#'s built in Xml class to handle it. Linq will help as well.

Here is code on how to get the values. You can extent this to use linq as I will explan below for mid levels as well (but your example above doesn't need it as the third level is not needed).

```
internal static LoadIndividualItem(XElement xelement)
{
    XElement element = ; //you need to pass the document as an Xelement somehow

    foreach (XElement child in element.Elements())
                {
                    string elementName = child.Name.ToString();

                    if (string.Compare(elementName, "item", true) == 0)
                    {
                        string name = child.Attribute(XName.Get("name"));
                        // Do something with this string

                        string name = child.Attribute(XName.Get("url"));
                        // Do something with this string\
                    }
                }
}
```

Here is an example of how to get the XElement.

```
public void LoadFromFile(string sourcXmlFileName = null)
{
    // Checks to see if file has been specified, if not assign it to the default value
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceXmdlFileName))
        sourceXmdlFileName = DefaultInventoryFile;

    // Check to make sure the file is there
        if (!File.Exists(sourceXmdlFileName))
            return;

    List<ObjectToHoldValues> MasterObject = new List<ObjectToHoldValues>();

            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(sourceXmlFileName, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // Create an xml document and assign it to a local variable
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

                // Load the roots
                foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("root"))
                {
                    ObjectToHoldValues itemList = new ObjectToHoldValues();
                    itemList = LoadIndividualItem(element);

                    MasterObject.Add(itemList);
                }
            }
}
```

You will want to create different controllers start at the root and use linq to move down each object adding different elements inside the tags. The bottom level tag might look something like this.

```
internal static LowLevelItem LowLevelFromXml(XElement element)
{
        return (
            // Create the Inventory item node
            new XElement("BottomLevel",
                // Create each child node of the values you need
                new XElement("ValueOne", _valueOne.ToString())
               ,new XElement("ValueTwo", _valueTwo));
}
```

The mid level objects might look like this

```
internal static MidLevelItem MidLevelItemFromXml(XElement element)
{
            XElement Root = new XElement("MidLevel");

            //Add all of the individual lower level records to the this root
            Root.Add(_lowerLevelItems
                .Select(item => item.LowLevelFromXml())
                .ToArray());

            return Root;
}
```

The top level might look like this

```
public void Save(string targetXmlFileName = null)
{
            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            XElement root = new XElement("TopLevel");

            //Add the root to the XML document
            doc.Add(root);

            //Add all of the subitems records to the XML document
            root.Add(_midLevelItem
                .Select(item => item.MidLevelItemFromXml())
                .ToArray());

            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
            {
                CloseOutput = true,
                Indent = true,
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };

            // Write the XML file
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(targetXmlFileName ?? DefaultFile, settings))
            {
                doc.Save(writer);
            }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understood how to convert an input XML file to List<ObjectToHoldValues> MasterObject, but I cannot grasp the root.Add(_midLevelItem...) part. Where are you calling MidLevelItemFromXml?

Comment: I took this from a file I had written. There the methods are all named the same ToXmlElement.  I made the correction here.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is just serialization and deserialization and modify objects.

What I would do is generate the the c# classes of both XML with XSD. Then create a method to convert each item to the other type. Then you can desserialize the input xml, use your new method and then serialize the new object.

Answer (score 0):

suppose if we have an XSLT file as shown below,which will be used to format an XML Document,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format'
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@`enter code here`* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/ReportTable">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all-pages" page-width="8.27in" page-height="11.69in">
          <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-left="0.7in" margin-right="0.7in" margin-top="0.7in" margin-bottom="0.7in" column-gap="0.25in" />
          <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="0.7in" display-align="after" padding-left="0.7in" padding-right="0.7in" margin-top="0.2in"  margin-bottom="0.4in"/>
          <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="0.7in" padding-left="0.7in" padding-right="0.7in" margin-top="0.2in"  margin-bottom="0.1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="default-sequence">
          <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="all-pages" />
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-sequence">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" >
          <fo:block  text-align="center" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline" line-height="200%">Page Title</fo:block>
          <fo:block line-height="70%" >
            &#x00A0;
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block line-height="200%">
            <!--to increase height  between line and Header -->

              <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(15.0)" column-number="1"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(45.0)" column-number="2"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(25.0)" column-number="3"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(15.0)" column-number="4"/>
              <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block text-align="center">
                      <fo:inline font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Node1"></xsl:value-of>
                      </fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block text-align="left">
                      <fo:inline text-align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Node2"></xsl:value-of>
                      </fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block text-align="right">
                      <fo:inline font-weight="bold" text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Node3"></xsl:value-of>
                      </fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block text-align="left">
                      <fo:inline text-align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Node4"></xsl:value-of>
                      </fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>  
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>&#x00A0; 
          </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" >
          <fo:block line-height="200%">
            <!--to increase height between line and footer-->
            <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" width="100%" table-layout="fixed" border-top-width="1pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-color="rgb(0,0,0)">
              <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="1"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="2"/>
              <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block text-align="center">
                      <fo:inline font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                        Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="documentEnd"/>
                      </fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block text-align="right">
                      <fo:inline font-weight="bold" text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="CurrentDate"></xsl:value-of>
                      </fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>&#x00A0;
          </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:table border-collapse='collapse' font-size='6pt' font-family='Arial'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='columns'></xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='rows'></xsl:apply-templates>
          </fo:table>
          <fo:block id="documentEnd"/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="columns">
    <xsl:for-each select="column">
      <fo:table-column column-width='80%'/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <fo:table-header font-weight='bold' font-size='8pt' line-height="200%" text-align="center" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-color="rgb(0,0,0)" border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="rgb(0,0,0)">
      <fo:table-row>
        <xsl:for-each select="column">
          <fo:table-cell padding='2pt'>
            <fo:block text-align='center'>
              <xsl:value-of select='@colName'/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here using XDOC we have created one XML Document and to convert this XML to another XML using XSLT Follow the below code,

```
    string[] ReportTableHeader = { "Headerone", "HeaderTwo", "HeaderTwo"};


XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("ReportTable",
                        new XElement("Node1", headerText1),
                        new XElement("Node2", headerText2),
                        new XElement("Node3",headerText3),
                        new XElement("Node4",headerText4),
                        new XElement("CurrentDate", footerCurDate),
                        new XElement("Columns", from col in ReportTableHeader
                                                              select
                                                                  new XElement("Column", new XAttribute("ColName", col.ToString().Trim())))));
XDocument finalXDoc = new XDocument();
                    using (XmlWriter inputStreamXSLT = finalXDoc.CreateWriter())
                    {
                        XslCompiledTransform objXSLT = new XslCompiledTransform();
                        string xsltFilePath = Server.MapPath(BasePage.GetReportPath(formName));
                        objXSLT.Load(xsltFilePath);
                        objXSLT.Transform(xdoc.CreateReader(), inputStreamXSLT);
                    }
                    string inputXMLtoXSLT = finalXDoc.ToString();
```

Here finalDoc is the XML Doc which is generated later,so we use finalDoc.CreateWriter() method and xDoc is the xml from which we are reading so we use xdoc.CreateReader() method and we are providing the path of the xslt file using Server.MapPath() Method.